# why lilipond-book is incompatible with both sweave and knitr on Lyx?

Tags: latex, knitr, sweave, lyx, lilypond

I was about to start some work on analysis of musical corpus with R as an personal exercise, and was baffled to discover that both sweave and knitr are incompatible with lilypond-book, leaving me to choose between some strategies to make the text, most of them consisting on including other texts on a master one.

What i want to understand is *why* those are incompatible. Those modules seem to be so far from each other in what they do that even guessing the reason is difficult to me... I was unable to find any info beyond the *fact* that they are incompatible, and at this moment, i find myself far from being able to analyse the sources to understand that.

**EDIT:**

This question was specific to Lyx, but I mistakenly marked it as latex only. I updated the question to better describe my doubt.

Comment: You need to give more background before anyone could possibly help you.  What goes wrong when you try that?  Where did you learn this "fact"?

Comment: Yes, i forgot to put the lyx tag, its the lyx _module_, not the latex _package_ that says it is incompatible. Thanks for stating the lack of info.